# Multiple microservices sharing an access token in AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, token, amazon-ecs

I have a scenario where I am consuming an external API that only responds if you are authenticated. The Auth is client credentials based auth i.e service to service not intended for end-users.

I am designing a client microservice that talks to this external API. However, once this microservice scales how do I share the access token returned by the external API between all instances of the client microservice?

Thank you so much for reading have a nice day!

Note: I am using AWS ECS.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to store the token in some central location where other instances of the service can read it. AWS Secrets Manager, AWS Parameter Store, and DynamoDB are all good possible locations for storing that token.

Also, you won't be able to use the ECS integration with Secrets Manager or Parameter Store for this. Since the value can change while ECS tasks are running, you'll need to write custom code in your application that reads and updates the value as needed.

Comment: To add, [Sean Jziegler's walkthrough](https://seanjziegler.com/a-complete-guide-to-using-the-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/) does a great job at explaining how to create new parameters, encrypted or not, in AWS Parameter Store, and shows how to leverage those parameters in your application.